# Update other items with the same title whenever one is changed

Tags: list, power-automate

I have a sharepoint list that keeps track of current project. I have "nested" the list  by having each phase of a project be its own list entry and then grouping by title. However some fields i want to update on all phases (Ex. I change the title from Cool project 1 -> cool project one) I dont want to manually change the title field on all entries. I've atempted to do this in power automate by making a condition on the title field
[image]

However as you might imagine this leads to an infinite loop(As this condition leads to updating an  item and that will the trigger the "Item modified" trigger used to start the flow). It dosent actually run infinitely but the result is inconsistent sometimes it will keep the old value sometimes it will update. Is there a better way to do this? or to make sure it dosent trigger itself? Ty in advance

Comment: Terminating the flow might work .  refer this article https://blog.enterprisedna.co/power-automate-terminate-action-control-in-flows/#:~:text=Adding%20A%20Terminate%20Control%20In%20Power%20Automate&text=Click%20the%20Switch%20statement.,Then%20click%20Terminate.

Comment: @RajatSahani Unfortunetly Terminate is not allowed in for each loops